# Repeat a request inside mergeMap, until its return value meets a certain condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I make several sequential requests and the result of `anotherRequest` is used in the second `mergeMap`-clause. This basically works fine.

My question is: How can I repeat `anotherRequest` until some condition is met and only pass the approved return-value to the second `mergeMap`-clause?

```
someRequest().pipe(
  mergeMap((info) => {
    this.appService.petitionId$.next(Number(lastInfo.petitionId));
    return anotherRequest();
  }),
  mergeMap(
    ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: you can use retry(), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113192/how-to-retry-a-subscription-when-it-fails-in-angular-9

Comment: Retry() repeats request if it was error, doesn’t it? I need to check condition if it is true, tnen pass result to MetgeMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `expand` in combination with `filter` and `take(1)`. By using the `expand`-operator the call will be repeated until a given condition is met. `filter` will make sure that an emission will only be made if the condition was met. And `take(1)` will trigger an unsubscribe after the first successful emission.

**[Here you can find my stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rpcsz3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

What's more, you can find the crucial part of my code below:

```
this.someRequest()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((info) => {
      return this.anotherRequest().pipe(
        expand((data) =>
          this.isConditionMet(data) ? of(data) : this.anotherRequest()
        ),
        filter((data) => this.isConditionMet(data)),
        take(1)
      );
    }),
    mergeMap((res) => {
      ...
    })
  )
```